# Rescheduled to delete more contacts in next off-peak period

Tags: kentico

In Kentico (9) when I run the task "Delete inactive contacts" it never actually runs and the result is always "Rescheduled to delete more contacts in next off-peak period"

I've tried changing the settings to run once a week and I've tried creating a custom IDeleteContacts then setting it to use that custom class, but I always get the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Kentico runs it's scheduled tasks in the tail of regular web requests. That's fine if you have traffic 24/7. If you don't, then you can run into all kinds of nastyness including the issue you're describing now because scheduled tasks are not executing.

If you're running on a Windows server you can setup a [service to trigger scheduled tasks](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/scheduling-tasks/installing-the-scheduler-windows-service). If that's not an option, you can setup monitoring to hit your site every couple of minutes, for example [UptimeRobot](http://uptimerobot.com) or [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability). You'll get the added bonus of being notified whenever the site goes down.

If you really need to clean up the EMS contacts because it's getting out of control, you can access the database directly and trigger the same stored procedure that the scheduled task uses. It's called `[Proc_OM_Contact_MassDelete]` and takes a where clause and a batch size. The where clause is where you specify the delete policy. For example

```
ContactCreated < GETDATE()-60 AND ([ContactEmail] IS NULL PR [ContactEmail]='')
```

With this where clause the stored proc would process contacts that were created over 60 days ago and don't have an e-mail address yet.

Please be aware that large volumes of EMS data will require database index tuning for this procedure to run within an acceptable period of time. This is true for EMS in general when your site has a decent amount of traffic.

If the standard Kentico cleanup doesn't work, for example because the database is unable to deal with millions of contacts, we've written a script to [purge all EMS data](https://gist.github.com/alanta/f2db6b5e358f22dd02fd3562cd41caeb). Use with caution ;)

Answer (score 0):

do you have applied the latest hotfix (9.0.50) on your project? There was a bug when the deletion of inactive contacts took longer than 1 minute, the next run of the "Delete inactive contacts" scheduled task was not set, and the task did not execute again. You can download the package directly from this page: https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

The "Delete inactive contacts" scheduled task only runs between 2am and 6am based on the servers time the site is running on.  You can [see this in the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/on-line-marketing-features/contact-management/working-with-contacts/setting-up-automatic-deletion-of-contacts).  It only ever deletes a batch of 1000 contacts and never more.  If you want to "trick" the site into running the scheduled task more, update the time on the server to 1:58am and restart the site.